# Retrieval of friends' emailID via Facebook API and user-permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

Below code gives permission to retrieve the logged in user's emailID. Similar to this, is there any way you can retrieve other user's emailID on passing facebook ID?

[[AppDelegateObj facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Similar to this, is there any way you can retrieve other user's emailID on passing facebook ID?

No. You can only access a user’s email, if they are using your app directly and have given you permission. There is no such thing as a `friends_email` permission.